# Native Video app does not play mpg files from a VCD

Tags: release-juno, applications, videos

I have a VCD with mpg files that the native Videos app does not play the video, it just shows blank screen, and no audio either. VLC player plays the same files successfully. I do see gstreamer1.0-plugins-* are installed with version 1.14.5, as these were listed as a solution in another similar question about native Video app not able to play video files that VLC player plays successfully.

Please let me know if further clarification/information on this topic is needed from my side that could help addressing this issue at hand.

Comment: You can report this issue to developers @ https://github.com/elementary/videos/issues

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have reported this issue - https://github.com/elementary/videos/issues/131